# Haskell cabal confused about file and module name

Tags: haskell, cabal

In my haskell project, I have the following directory structure (some entries are missing but not relevant to this problem)

```
- quanthas
   - quanthas.cabal
   - src/
      - QuantHas/
         - Settings.hs
```

My Settings.hs file contains this module header

```
module QuantHas.Settings(module QuantHas.Settings) where
```

My cabal file looks like this

```
Name:               QuantHas
Version:            0.0
Description:
    QuantHas project is an attempt to port QuantLib to Haskell keeping the functional flavor of Haskell.
License:            BSD3
License-file:       LICENSE
Build-Type:         Simple
Cabal-Version:      >=1.10

Library
  Build-Depends:    base >= 3 && < 5, array >= 0.2
  Exposed-modules:  QuantHas.Time.Frequency
                QuantHas.Time.TimeUnit
                QuantHas.Time.Period
                QuantHas.Time.Date
                QuantHas.Time.DayCounter
                QuantHas.Time.BusinessDayConvention
                QuantHas.Time.Calendar
                QuantHas.Time.Calendars.UnitedKingdom
                QuantHas.Time.Schedule
                QuantHas.Settings
                QuantHas.Require
  default-language: Haskell2010                 
  hs-source-dirs:   src
  --  ghc-options:      -Wall

test-suite QuantHas-tests
  type: exitcode-stdio-1.0
  hs-source-dirs: testsuite
  main-is: Tests.hs
  default-language: Haskell2010
```

When I execute

```
cabal install --enable-tests
```

I get this message

```
src/Quanthas/Settings.hs:17:8: error:
   File name does not match module name:
   Saw: ‘QuantHas.Settings’
   Expected: ‘Quanthas.Settings’
```

This seems wrong.  However, what if we do what cabal expects.  So the Settings.hs module header now is

```
module Quanthas.Settings(module Quanthas.Settings) where
```

Cabal now says

```
src/QuantHas/Settings.hs:17:8: error:
   File name does not match module name:
   Saw: ‘Quanthas.Settings’
   Expected: ‘QuantHas.Settings’
```

And it's at this ppint that I give up and turn to SO.  Can anyone help me understand what is going on?

Versions info:
   Platform: Macbook Pro running MacOS 10.12.3
   Haskell: 8.0.1
   Cabal: 1.24.0.0

Thanks!

Comment: So are you certain the `QuantHas` directory in the filesystem is named with the uppercase `H`?  If so, did you do something like start with lowercase and later rename it?  Wondering if it can be some caching thing.

Comment: Yes, it has always had an 'H' in the directory name.

Comment: Tried `cabal configure` after changing?

Comment: Your errors clearly states the directory name - `src/Quanthas/Settings.hs:17:8: error:` and `src/QuantHas/Settings.hs:17:8: error:`. As far as your machine is concerned, your claim that the directory has always been named `QuantHas` is simply false. In these sorts of matters, I am inclined to believe the machine.

Comment: Is it possible that your filesystem is case-insensitive? In such a case, sometimes a file may be *accessed* at e.g. name `X/Y/Z` even though if you asked the filesystem what files were in `X` it would tell you about `y/z`. I guess it's not too surprising to think this would confuse tools like cabal/GHC. If this is the problem, making a partition with a case-sensitive filesystem should fix things up.

Comment: Perhaps you have a typo in one of your import statements, and OS X's case insensitivity is just causing lots of confusion.

Comment: @MichaelSnoyman yes that was it! thank you.  I went through all the places where the module was imported and found one 'h' instead of an 'H' in an import statement.  The error message led me to believe it was just the module and its file that was the cause of the problem.  If you want to make this an answer, I can upvote it etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The issue is that there is a typo in one of the import statements in a different module. Since you're on a case-insensitive filesystem (OS X), GHC is able to find the module contents, but upon checking the module header finds it mismatches with the import statement and errors out.